# What do the number prefixes mean in explain operator?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What does `(1)`, `(6)` and `(3)` mean in the following output of `explain`. Spark version is 2.3.1.

[image]

Comment: Strange thing, I've ran several `explain` against synthetic data frames and don't see these number.
Can you share code snippet please, so I can reproduce this on my env?

Comment: @morsik The numbers were added around Spark 2.2. What's your Spark version?

Comment: I use 2.2.0 too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it was around Spark 2.0 when Spark SQL started generating Java code for some parts of structured queries. That feature is called **Whole-Stage Java Code Generation** (aka *Whole-Stage CodeGen*).

Whole-Stage Java Code Generation (aka Whole-Stage CodeGen) is simply a physical query optimization in Spark SQL that fuses multiple physical operators (as a subtree of plans that support code generation) together into a single Java function.

You can learn about that Java-generated code parts of a structured query using `explain` operator.

```
val q = spark.range(5)
  .groupBy('id % 2 as "g")
  .agg(collect_list('id) as "ids")
  .join(spark.range(5))
  .where('id === 'g)
scala> q.explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) BroadcastHashJoin [g#1266L], [id#1272L], Inner, BuildRight
:- *(3) Filter isnotnull(g#1266L)
:  +- ObjectHashAggregate(keys=[(id#1264L % 2)#1278L], functions=[collect_list(id#1264L, 0, 0)])
:     +- Exchange hashpartitioning((id#1264L % 2)#1278L, 200)
:        +- ObjectHashAggregate(keys=[(id#1264L % 2) AS (id#1264L % 2)#1278L], functions=[partial_collect_list(id#1264L, 0, 0)])
:           +- *(1) Range (0, 5, step=1, splits=8)
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]))
   +- *(2) Range (0, 5, step=1, splits=8)
```

As you noticed, I have a query with 3 starred round-bracketed numbers. These adornment (the star and the numbers) are all part of whole-stage java code generation optimization.

The numbers denote **WholeStageCodegen subtrees** for which Spark SQL generates separate functions that all together are the underlying code that Spark SQL uses to execute the query.

You can see the code and the subtrees using `debug` implicit interface.

```
scala> q.queryExecution.debug.codegen
Found 3 WholeStageCodegen subtrees.
== Subtree 1 / 3 ==
*(1) Range (0, 5, step=1, splits=8)

Generated code:
...
```

Comment: @thebluephantom Sure. You were not. Eventually you end up with RDDs and tasks as for most structured queries.